# MySQL deadlock when updating the whole table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-deadlocks

I've been struggling to get to the bottom of a deadlock issue we've been having when we go to materialise some columns when something has changed elsewhere in the database.

Essentially the materialisation routine resets the relevant columns to NULL then adds values where necessary (as for most items the columns will remain NULL).

Here's a couple of example queries:

```
UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = NULL, `edit_user_ids` = NULL ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position

UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '9,6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 3 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/3/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/3')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
```

I've only seen the problem in production (making it harder to troubleshoot), and it occurs much more often when I do the materialisation as part of the request that changed the other related data than it does when I queue it up as a `delayed_job` executed soon after the request has finished.

My only ideas are to remove the ordering, which doesn't matter in these cases. And possibly look at indexes?

I have a hunch that it's happening when multiple requests trigger these materialisations at around the same time and they're stepping on each others toes?

Please let me know what other information will be handy to know.

**UPDATE**

Here's the output (or the start of it) of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
160406 23:03:05
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3A787847, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 437042, OS thread handle 0x7f488b80c700, query id 13820202 localhost xxxxxxxxxxxx init
UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,25,26,29,30,35,37,38,39,40' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 125 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/14/22/125/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/14/22/125')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 124313 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `450273b5d362920c`.`component_instances` trx id 3A787847 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 19 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 19; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 8000007d; asc    };;
1: len 6; hex 00003a787842; asc   :xxB;;
2: len 7; hex 54000217c52716; asc T    ' ;;
3: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
4: len 4; hex 80000021; asc    !;;
5: SQL NULL;
6: len 4; hex 50616765; asc Page;;
7: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
8: SQL NULL;
9: SQL NULL;
10: SQL NULL;
11: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
12: len 7; hex 312f31342f3232; asc 1/14/22;;
13: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;
14: len 30; hex 4c6974657261637920617420546175706f205072696d617279205363686f; asc Literacy at XXXXXXXXXXX Scho; (total 32 bytes);
15: SQL NULL;
16: len 6; hex 332c342c3135; asc 3,4,15;;
17: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
18: SQL NULL;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3A787846, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
180 lock struct(s), heap size 31160, 12416 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 437041, OS thread handle 0x7f488b6e6700, query id 13820201 localhost xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx init
UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = NULL, `edit_user_ids` = NULL ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 124313 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of table `450273b5d362920c`.`component_instances` trx id 3A787846 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

**UPDATE 2**

There is currently an index on the `ancestry` column and that's it (apart from `ID`).

There are currently no transactions around these updates:

```
UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = NULL, `edit_user_ids` = NULL ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  Permission Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `permissions` LIMIT 1
  ComponentInstance Load (17.0ms)  SELECT component_instances.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT view_groups_users.user_id) AS calculated_view_user_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT edit_groups_users.user_id) AS calculated_edit_user_ids FROM `component_instances` LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions ON permissions.component_instance_id = component_instances.id LEFT OUTER JOIN groups view_groups ON view_groups.id = permissions.group_id AND permissions.view = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN groups edit_groups ON edit_groups.id = permissions.group_id AND permissions.edit = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN groups_users view_groups_users ON view_groups_users.group_id = view_groups.id LEFT OUTER JOIN groups_users edit_groups_users ON edit_groups_users.group_id = edit_groups.id GROUP BY component_instances.id ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry
  SQL (4.5ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 2 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/2/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/2')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (6.9ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '9,6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 3 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/3/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/3')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '9' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 6 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/3/6/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/3/6')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = '6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 9 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/3/9/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/3/9')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = '9' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 118 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/118/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/118')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = '9,6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 120 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (2.3ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '9' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 120 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = '9' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 119 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/119/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120/119')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '9' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 119 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/119/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120/119')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `view_user_ids` = '6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 121 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/121/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120/121')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `edit_user_ids` = '6' WHERE (((`component_instances`.`id` = 121 OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` LIKE '1/120/121/%') OR `component_instances`.`ancestry` = '1/120/121')) ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  SQL (3.9ms)  UPDATE `component_instances` SET `recursively_visible` = 1 ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
  ComponentInstance Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `component_instances`.* FROM `component_instances` WHERE `component_instances`.`visible` = 0 ORDER BY component_instances.ancestry, position
```

**UPDATE 3**

My suspicion is that the large query above is ordering differently from the rest of the queries. I've fixed this in my production code to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Comment: Can you show us what queries cause the deadlock? You can find by the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, see [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1740/89670) for details (assuming you use the INNODB engine). From this you can find whether it is really two requests at the same time that cause the deadlocks (most likely, IMO) or something else.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Innodb.

Comment: @BoraMa: I've updated the question to include the debug. There was a whole lot more below that but that's the two statements. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What indexes are currently in place? How are you using transactions?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix, I've updated the question to include that information (see Update 2)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario the problem was a difference in the `ORDER BY` clause of a couple of different bits of SQL being run around the same time. I overrode the incorrect ordering and all has been well since.